# Alternatives to Agartha

Tags: the-secret-world

For miscellaneous reasons I am unable to travel to agartha, which is the usual means by which I get to various places.

Is there a way to travel between areas other than by going through agartha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, kind of. But it requires a second player. When playing in a group you can teleport to your group members via the context-menu.

Comment: How is the context menu invoked, what is the text of the context menu option?

Answer (score 4):

I have found a way to do this that involves using a feature of the game called "meet up" this is somewhat similar to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/177791/61492), but requires adding other players to your friends list and then selecting "meet up" from the context menu.